# How to rename files in folder

Tags: lua

There are 2 files with chaotic names like(5E4894837047C68DDC7F0AF96C7D84F2DEB7462D  and 9B0DBA6BFBB5AFD06CF436232234FAFAD12F6412) placed in folder.How to rename them to file1.jpg and file2.jpg one by one in lua?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but there is an `os.rename` function:
https://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=os.rename
I hope this helps.

Comment: thank u. not what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function to scandir your directory with files
2. For each file, use [`os.rename`](https://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=os.rename) function to rename it

Example for a `scandir` function :

```lua
local function scandir(directory)
    local i, t, popen = 0, {}, io.popen
    local pfile = popen('ls -a "'..directory..'"')
    for filename in pfile:lines() do
        i = i + 1
        t[i] = filename
    end
    pfile:close()
    return t
end

local files = scandir(<directory>)

for i, file in pairs(files) do os.rename(file, 'file'.. i ..'.jpg') end
```